# не могу найти ошибку 100 раз все пересмотрела помогите

Tags: html, css

Надо картинки выстроить по горизонтали`float:left;`. Но у меня ничего не срабатывает. Почему?

```css
html {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
} 
/*_____Grid_____*/

.container {
    width: 1140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 360px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.col-4:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
/*
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;

*/
/*_______Header Start________*/

.header {
  background: #343c4e;
  background-image: url("../img/bg/bg-header.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  
  height: 100vh;
  
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  position: relative;  
}

.header__title {
  font-size: 56px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  margin-top: -50px; 
} 

.header__slogan {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.header__arrow {
  font-size: 48px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left:50%;  
}

/*_____ Header end_______*/
/*_____Portfolio Start_____*/
.title {
  font-size: 46px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  font-family5px;: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-align: center;  
}
.portfolio-item__img {
  margin-bottom: 17px;  
}
.portfolio-item__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.portfolio-item__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Сайт портфолио</title>
  <!--Нормализация стилeй-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css">
   <!--Собственные стили-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <!--Подключение веб-шрифтов-->  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|PT+Sans+Caption:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/x-icon"href="img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <!--Подключаем шрифты,стили END-->
</head>
<body>
<!--HEADER Start-->
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__title">Бабенко Артем</div>
  <div class="header__slogan">Верстка сайтов на HTML и CSS<br>HTML5 CSS3JS jQuery</div>
  <div class="header__arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
</div>
<!--HEADER End-->

<!--Portfolio Start-->
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      Портфолио
    </div>
     <div class="row">
       <!--Paбота в портфолио-->
        <div class="col-4">
         <div class="portfolio-item__img">
           <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Проект Органика">
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__title">
           <a href="#">Макет Органика</a>
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__text">
          <p>Верстка одностраничного сайта по PSD макету.</p>
         </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
      <!--//Paбота в портфолио-->
      <!--Paбота в портфолио-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
         <div class="portfolio-item__img">
           <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Учебный макет Апполо">
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__title">
           <a href="#">Учебный макет Апполо</a>
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__text">
          <p>Верстка лейдинга хостинг компании.Мобильная адаптивность.</p>
         </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
      <!--//Paбота в портфолио-->
      <!--Paбота в портфолио-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
         <div class="portfolio-item__img">
           <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Личный сайт портфолио">
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__title">
           <a href="#">Личный сайт портфолио</a>
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__text">
          <p>Верстка личного сайта портфолио на котором вы сейчас находитесь.</p>
         </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
      <!--//Paбота в портфолио-->
    </div>
  </div>
<!--_______________________________________________

FOOTER

___________________________________________________-->
 
 
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
} 
/*_____Grid_____*/

.container {
    width: 1140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 360px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.col-4:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
/*
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;

*/
/*_______Header Start________*/

.header {
  background: #343c4e;
  background-image: url("../img/bg/bg-header.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  
  height: 100vh;
  
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  position: relative;  
}

.header__title {
  font-size: 56px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  margin-top: -50px; 
} 

.header__slogan {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.header__arrow {
  font-size: 48px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left:50%;  
}

/*_____ Header end_______*/
/*_____Portfolio Start_____*/
.title {
  font-size: 46px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-align: center;  
}
.portfolio-item__img {
  margin-bottom: 17px;  
}
.portfolio-item__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.portfolio-item__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Сайт портфолио</title>
  <!--Нормализация стилeй-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css">
   <!--Собственные стили-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <!--Подключение веб-шрифтов-->  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|PT+Sans+Caption:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/x-icon"href="img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <!--Подключаем шрифты,стили END-->
</head>
<body>
<!--HEADER Start-->
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__title">Бабенко Артем</div>
  <div class="header__slogan">Верстка сайтов на HTML и CSS<br>HTML5 CSS3JS jQuery</div>
  <div class="header__arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
</div>
<!--HEADER End-->

<!--Portfolio Start-->
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      Портфолио
    </div>
     <div class="row">
       <!--Paбота в портфолио-->
        <div class="col-4">
         <div class="portfolio-item__img">
           <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Проект Органика">
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__title">
           <a href="#">Макет Органика</a>
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__text">
          <p>Верстка одностраничного сайта по PSD макету.</p>
         </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-4">
         <div class="portfolio-item__img">
           <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Учебный макет Апполо">
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__title">
           <a href="#">Учебный макет Апполо</a>
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__text">
          <p>Верстка лейдинга хостинг компании.Мобильная адаптивность.</p>
         </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-4">
         <div class="portfolio-item__img">
           <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Личный сайт портфолио">
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__title">
           <a href="#">Личный сайт портфолио</a>
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-item__text">
          <p>Верстка личного сайта портфолио на котором вы сейчас находитесь.</p>
         </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
      <!--//Paбота в портфолио-->
    </div>
  </div>
<!--_______________________________________________

FOOTER

___________________________________________________-->
 
 
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Вы каждую работу оборачиваете в `.row`. У него ширина 100%. Нужно все 3 работы обернуть в 1 `.row`.

И ещё:

```
/*_____Portfolio Start_____*/
.title {
    font-size: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    font-family`**5px;**`: 'Merriweather', serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Ребята ,спасибо большое все получилось.Видно сказывалась ночь.